# Dropdown list options punctuation

Tags: dropdown, drop-down-list, ux-writing

is it best practice to have periods at the end of a dropdown list item? I understand using question marks if the options are questions but if each option is a statement, should we use a period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question Marks and Ellipses are often used in drop-down menus, but periods almost never are. Being consistent with universal standards would mean not using any periods in a drop-down.